# Need to convert an Excel formula to a Google Sheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a formula that works in Excel but cannot get it to work in Google Sheets. Can someone please help?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("amp",$A2)), "AMP", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("feed",$A2)), "Feed", "Other"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that will work in google sheets.

Comment: I added it into a google sheet document and it does not work. The affected cell just shows the formula. It's not computing for some reason. Right now, the affected cell indicates a formula parse error.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: It is not the formula itself that is wrong but the implimentation and we cannot help without seeing the actual sheet.

Comment: Yes, you are correct concerning the show formula issue. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

try perhaps:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("amp";  A2)); "AMP", 
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("feed"; A2)); "Feed"; "Other"))
```